# How to upload screenshots using Quill text editor

Tags: angular, mean-stack, quill

I'm a beginner in Angular. I'm making a technical blog website. This is my first ever Angular project. I'm using `MEAN` stack. Everything is working absolutely perfect, except image upload through `quill`. Sorry I cannot paste the entire code here as it will be too confusing here. Here is my **contribute.component.html**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row pt-5">
    ...
    <quill-editor [styles]="editorStyle" [modules]="config" ...></quill-editor>
  </div>
</div>
```

And **contribute.component.ts**

```
  config = {
    toolbar: [
      ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'strike'],
      ['image','code-block'],
      [{ 'list': 'ordered'}, { 'list': 'bullet' }],
      [{ 'script': 'sub'}, { 'script': 'super' }],
      [{ 'size': ['small', false, 'large', 'huge'] }],
      [{ 'header': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, false] }],
      [{ 'color': [] }, { 'background': [] }],
      [{ 'font': [] }],
      ['link']
    ]
  }
```

The document structure in Mongodb is like:

```
  makeNewPost={
    articleid: "",
    title: "",
    content: "", <----screenshots should be included with this
    date: "",
    contributor: ""
  };
```

And I'm sorry, creating stackblitz is also not possible. But here's the entire project: [GitHub](https://github.com/tmtanzeel/social-coder).
The file which are responsible for this system is at this location:

1. **social-coder/application/src/app/contribute/contribute.html**
2. **social-coder/application/src/app/contribute/contribute.ts**

I'm getting his error whenever I try to upload an image along with the content:

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:3000/api/contribute. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).
>
> Object { headers: {…}, status: 0, statusText: "Unknown Error", url: "http://localhost:3000/api/contribute", ok: false, name: "HttpErrorResponse", message: "Http failure response for http://localhost:3000/api/contribute: 0 Unknown Error", error: error }

You can use my credentials for now:

> User: demouser@nomail.com
>
> Pass: test12_mail

Please correct me.

Here is the deployed application: [SocialCoder](http://socialcoder-6291.herokuapp.com/). Please login with the above credentials. But you'll not find any `image` tool because I've not merged with the master yet.

Comment: I don't believe this is a problem with Quill. Try removing / uninstalling Quill from your project, and check if the same error appears.

Comment: I'm using Quill editor to upload the screenshot. How is that unrelated to Quill? And removing Quill is definitely not a solution.